# Different Page Number Styles

Tags: page-numbering

I would like to use roman page numbers (i, ii, iii, etc.) at the beginning of a report I am writing. In the main area of the report, I would like to use Arabic page numbers in the page of pages (1 of XX, 2 of XX, etc.) I am using the article class. I have seen articles of how to use both roman and Arabic format but not with the changes in page numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: `\frontmatter` for the roman page numbers, for the `page of pages` use header package, e.g. `fancyhdr` and the `lastpage` package

Comment: You need to switch from report to book [oneside] class to use \frontmatter.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Oh my, I did not notice `article class` in the post above. Of course `article.cls` does not provide `\frontmatter`. You're right about `report` or `book`

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The response below worked for me. I will try your suggestions as well. I have not used LaTeX for a while and would like to learn it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `article` document class, by design, does not provide the convenient directives `\frontmatter` and `mainmatter`. However, it's not too difficult to create your desired setup by loading the packages `fancyhdr` and `pageslts`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\usepackage{pageslts}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman} % switch to roman numerals
\cfoot{\thepage} % place page number centered in footer line

\section*{AAA}
\lipsum[1-15] % 2+ pages of filler text

\clearpage % start a new page
\pagenumbering{arabic} % switch to arabic numerals, start over at "1"
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \lastpageref{pagesLTS.arabic}}
% (Use \lastpageref*` if also using the `hyperref` package.)

\section{BBB}
\lipsum[1-20] % 3+ pages of filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: how about this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395308/different-page-number-styles ?

Comment: +1, this I meant sorry https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/492327/41144

Comment: @wonderich - Thanks for the follow-up. I've gone ahead and posted an answer to your query.