# Change the page numbering to "(roman) - AAA"

Tags: page-numbering

This is an extended question from: [Different Page Number Styles](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395308/different-page-number-styles)

How to change the page numbering to something like:

Page 1 numbering:  (i) - AAA.

Page 2 numbering:  (ii) - AAA.

Page 3 numbering:  (iii) - AAA.

...

where the AAA can be the author name, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`fancyhdr`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr?lang=en) package. A two-page example is below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{Baby!}
\lhead{Oh yeah}
\rfoot{\thepage \, - Author Name}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks +1 - great to know

Answer (score 2):

The following is an adaptation/simplification of an [earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/395311/5001) that uses the `fancyhdr` package and its `\cfoot` instruction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}        % for filler text

\usepackage{fancyhdr}      % see https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{}                 % clear headers and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % no header rule
\pagenumbering{roman}      % switch to roman-numeral numbering
\cfoot{(\thepage) --- AAA} % center-set page number

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20] % almost 4 pages of filler text
\end{document}
```

Of course, you are free to replace "AAA" with something more informative and important.

Here's a screenshot of the lower part of page 3:

[image]